# Spring boot authentication issue - always redirected to /login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have troubles with Spring Security. I want to override the built-in `/login` endpoint from spring in order to be able to load mylogin.html page which is located under `resources/templates/mylogin.html`. I think that this issue comes from the below code. Also, the class is annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`.

The security bean configuration from my project:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    //The pages does not require login
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/welcome","logout").permitAll();
    // /userInfo page requires login as ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DOCTOR, ROLE_PATIENT
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/userInfo").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_DOCTOR','ROLE_PATIENT')");
    //For ADMIN only
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");
    http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    //Config for Login Form
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/mylogin.html")
            .permitAll(true)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/mylogin.html?logout")
            .permitAll();code here
}
```

Is someone who can help me?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf library. You can do

`.loginPage("/login")`

Then with Spring Controller, you can catch the /login request in a method. In this method, return "mylogin" will redirect user to the mylogin.html page.

Example here: https://github.com/cihangir-mercan/spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it !